# unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'Queue' and 'int' after implementing '__rrshift__'

Tags: python, oop

```
class Queue:

    queue_list: list

    def __init__(self, *args: int) -> None:
        self.queue_list = list(args)

    ...

    def __rrshift__(self, i: int) -> Queue:
            result: Queue = self.copy()
            try:
                result.queue_list = self.queue_list[i:]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            return result
```

```
q3 = Queue(2, 3, 4, 5)
q4 = Queue(1, 2)
q4 += q3 >> 4
print(q4)
```

```
File "c:\...\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    q4 += q3 >> 4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'Queue' and 'int'
```

`>>` must return new `Queue()` with `self.queue_list[i:]` if it possible else clear `Queue()`.

What is the error?

Comment: Why do you expect the `>>` to work? Because you have defined `__rrshift__`? In your own words, what does that mean? Did you try to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in order to understand which method is needed for the operator?  Or [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+operator+overloading) for a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__rrshift__` implements the operation where a `Queue` instance is on the right-hand side of the `>>` operator.

In order to be able to use `q3 >> 4`, where a `Queue` is on the left-hand side you need to implement `__rshift__`.

---

The syntax `a >> b` is equivalent to `a.__rshift__(b)`. If this method isn't defined for the object `a` it then looks up `b.__rrshift__(a)`, i.e. the additional `r` prefix stands for *reverse* operator.

So in your case `q3 >> 4` needs `q3.__rshift__(4)`.

If you have implemented `__rrshift__` you can do `4 >> q3`, because `int.__rshift__` isn't defined with a `Queue` as argument (to be more precise it raises a `NotImplemented` exception), so it then uses `q3.__rrshift__(4)`.